# Is it an eclipse or maven-compiler-plugin bug, the generics Class cast issue?

Tags: eclipse, generics, maven-plugin, javac, jls

I have a code like this:

```
protected <T> T doSomething(String someParam, Class<T> clazz) {
...
}
```

which I use in a TestCase class:

```
Class clazz = MyClass.class;
MyClass MyClass = someObject.doSomething(someString, clazz);
```

**This code gives a warning in eclipse**:

> Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class should be parameterized

and

> Multiple markers at this line
>       - Type safety: Unchecked invocation doSomething(String, Class) of the generic method doSomething(String, Class) of type MyClass
>       - Type safety: The expression of type Class needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class

**When I run this code (test) in eclipse - everything works perfectly. When I do it through "mvn clean install" through command prompt**, I get:

> C:\pathToProject\src\test\java\packagesPath\MyTestCase.java:[xx,xxx] incompatible types found   :
>   java.lang.Object
>   required: com.somePackagePath.MyClass

But when providing:

```
Class<MyClass> clazz = MyClass.class;
MyClass MyClass = someObject.doSomething(someString, clazz);
```

**I don't get any errors nor warnings.** .
I understand that java compiler [erases type info](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so:
***Shouldn't eclipse provide a compiler error instead of warning, or is it the maven-plugin-compiler that creates the problem?***
The maven plugin is:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                <debug>true</debug>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Kind Regards,
Despot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in Eclipse: [333011: [compiler][1.5] Eclipse compiles codes which javac rejects: incompatible types](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=333011) . Feel free to vote for the bug and add your use case to it.

---

There are situations when `javac` and Eclipse disagree, and you should report them as bugs. It is preferred to have a standalone test case of as few Java files as possible which can be copy/pasted in Eclipse and compiled using `javac` from the command line without any dependencies.

Comment: I had a discussion with a colegue of mine, who argues that the eclipse compiler is just being "smarter" that the maven compiler and can notice that Class clazz = MyClass.class; is of type MyClass, because on the right side of the expression we have a simple statement. I would say that either java specification should be changed to accommodate this behavior or the eclipse compiler shouldn't do this - it will create problems for other compilers. Right?

Comment: Fact is that the Java Language Specification is set in stone. Once a compiler is written is _must_ obey it. I agree that a smart compiler can infer much more than what javac and eclipsec currently do, but that would make it non-compliant - useless. 

In this specific instance the eclipse compiler is non-compliant and should be fixed.

And another note: it is not the maven compiler, it is the maven-compiler-_plugin_ which is invoking javac under the hood, so the comparison is between eclipsec and javac.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler are you using? 
In this case http://code.google.com/p/jclouds/issues/detail?id=461 the openjdk seems to reveal the incompatible types while the sun jdk ignores it and compiles.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is using eclipse compiler in maven as described at [Using Eclipse Java Compiler (ecj) in maven builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164976/using-eclipse-java-compiler-ecj-in-maven-builds)